# important changes of linux 3.1 to 3.17

Tags: linux, history, version

I'm doing school research project for Linux operating system and I need to understand the summary of version 3.1 to 3.17. I to make a basic structure of the most important changes/additions to the system.

Comment: P.S. There is an [English Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/), and I suspect that the participants there are technically inclined and can help with your understanding of any phrasing you don't understand in these Linux documents.  Also, you may want to fill out your profile, so we can find out about you, including what part of the world you are in and what level of school you are in.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what's listed in *release notes*.  Linux is a kernel; the *system* includes many programs written by different groups (such as Gnu) with their own release history and numbering.

Re English, note that `release notes` is a good search term to use with Google etc.